# AWS EC2 billing API : Reserved host pricing not available

Tags: amazon-ec2

I downloaded the EC2 pricing csv file using the url  https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.csv . It is not listing the pricing for reserved hosts . example , if I want to check pricing for m3 : dedictaed host with 3 year reservation, it does not have the price listed .

Any input .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, some definitions:

- There is no such thing as a **Reserved Host**.
- A **Dedicated Host** is a physical host computer that is charged per-hour. You pay for the whole host immediately, and can then launch individual instances (for free) onto the host.
- A **Reserved Instance** is a pricing discount.

The pricing file you linked contained the following lines for:

- **Region:** us-east-1
- **Term:** Reserved
- **Instance Type:** m3.xlarge (you must select a single instance type for the whole host)
- **Tenancy:** Dedicated
- **Pre-installed software (eg SQL Server):** None

[image: Decicated Host pricing]

If using **All Upfront** pricing, there is no hourly fee.

If using **Partial Upfront** pricing, there is a an upfront fee plus a discounted hourly fee.

---

**Update:**

Singapore partial-upfront m4 Linux dedicated hosts:

[image: dedicated m4 singapore]

Yes, this indeed does *not* correlate with the pricing page, which merely shows a price for "m4". It does not match m4.10xlarge nor m4.16xlarge.

You should contact AWS Customer Service for clarification on the costs.

Comment: if I want to reserve an m4 host in Singapore with 1-yr- reservation and partial payment , I need to pay 7844$ upfront and monthly 653.35 $ . I could not find such line in the excel . similarly for other regions and other host types . https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/pricing/

Comment: let me know if you got the problem I am highlighting.

Comment: You are right -- the pricing file does not match what is shown on the AWS pricing page. You should contact AWS Customer Service for clarification on the costs.

Comment: Now looks like all EBS pricing data is missing in latest version of excel sheet at "https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.csv" .. all my APIs are failing..in a mess..

Comment: I don't know why it is failing for you but, FYI, there is a new API-driven Price List service. See: [AWS Price List API Update – New Query and Metadata Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-new-query-and-metadata-functions/)

Comment: Hello John, was there a reduction in ec2 pricing recently ? I notice some changes but did not see announcements . Are you aware of the details ?

Comment: Price reductions are typically announced on [the AWS blog - price reduction tag](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/price-reduction/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check how much things will cost in AWS is using the [Simple Monthly Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?lng=de_DE)

For the actual costs of your infrastructure I would suggest digesting the [CUR](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/aws-cost-and-usage-reports-comprehensive-and-customizable-reporting-on-your-aws-costs-and-cost-drivers/) report from AWS, which contains on which instance your RI was applied, how many hours, dedicated servers, etc.

Check the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html